# How code completion in GAS works?

Tags: google-apps-script, behavior, code-completion

Is there a detailed description on the "rules" of code completion (CC) in GAS..? Sometimes the CC works perfectly even when I move the cursor back in a code line and sometimes it won't work at all even when there are only three lines of code and everything is defined unambiguously.

```
ss.getActiveSheet(); // If I go back to "ss" and type a period, it will open 
                     // up CC. (Most times.)

ss.getActiveSheet(); // But also sometimes, even after the "getActiveSheet()," 
                     // when I put a period, nothing happens.
```

I know that when you copy and paste code, that it messes it up. But in some cases, it just stops working on a script I've been working on for a long time.

So can someone explain the "rules" of CC? That way the behavior can be understood and, in turn, stops people like me from doing something that stops CC for long scripts. It is getting really irritating having to look up methods, especially when chaining.

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing to explain... this has been flaky recently. When I see it take a nap, I usually save my script, then hit the browser 'reload'. Most times, it comes back happy.

Comment: Fully agree ... When I see it take a nap....I usually take a nap too :-) .More seriously, the 'reload' trick works indeed quite often, sometimes I paste my code in a new script when it's really broken and that usually works.

Comment: Bummer! Well, I guess I'll just keep refreshing. Thanks guys!

Comment: Looking it up manually provides incentive to memorize.

Comment: Also try writing a short new function, that includes the built-in service you're using, **above** the one that has lost auto complete.